# Are websockets suitable for use with PHP?

Tags: php, html, sockets, websocket

I have seen it mentioned in various places around the internet that HTML5 websockets do not work well with PHP, that PHP by it's nature is just suitable for use with them. On the other hand, I see multiple tutorials on using PHP with websockets and Ive noticed some PHP websocket implementation such as http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

So does anyone have any definitive information on using websockets with PHP. Are they usable with PHP, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using them with PHP as opposed to Java or Python, and why have I read numerous people saying they don't work well together?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about NodeJS and socket.io. It depends on your project but it might give you what you need: [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org) [socket.io](http://socket.io)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that WebSockets are designed for long running threads/processes which each maintain multiple event-driven connections, whereas PHP (and it's Apache cohort) was designed around the short-lived single process procedural paradigm (eg. [`max_execution_time` is commonly set to 30 seconds](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), and the session is single threaded).

That's not to say that it's impossible to write a WebSockets server implementation in PHP.  I'm aware of at least one project exists that has [done exactly this](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) (but note, even this example gets run from the command line, not through `mod_php`).  But it is likely that the PHP implementation of WebSockets is incompatible with the setup of the cheap/shared hosting where PHP is most commonly used.

So while it's possible to it in PHP, you end up having to run a separate server process (from Apache) anyway, and if you're on the sort of hosting that allows separate server processes then it's easier to write WebSockets code in something which is designed for event-driven programming.

If you're not planning to serve tens of thousands of concurrent duplex connections then it's likely you'd be better off using a combination of AJAX and [SSE](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) with your PHP back-end.

Comment: What about php-fpm? And php7 with JIT technology? This answer should be updated.

Answer (score -1):

I recently tried phpwebsocket and it doesn't work at this time (php 5.4 and chrome) the code refers to a secondkey in the handshake that doesn't exist in rev. 13 of the websocket protocol I don't have the time to read the RFC to understand what's the matter.

It's sure that this solution is more elegant and reactive than AJAX with long polling but websockets are not stable at this time I think it would be more interesting to wait that the w3c announce it stable.